# how to load libandroid_runtime

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I'm working on a project that gets compiled into a JAR and then deployed using javaws. In one of my classes, I need to load the libandroid_runtime.so found in directory /system/lib/ on the device.

How do I do this?

System.load("libandroid_runtime")throws
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: libandroid_runtime

System.loadLibrary("/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so") throws  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so.

System.loadLibrary("android_runtime"); throws  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no android_runtime in java.library.path

thanks!

Comment: most likely, `/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so` is already loaded for your app

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a project that gets compiled into a JAR and then deployed using javaws

Android does not use Java Web Start.

> In one of my classes, I need to load the libandroid_runtime.so found in directory /system/lib/ on the device.

That is not possible. You do not have read access to `/system`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.loadLibrary("android_runtime");` requires the library libandroid_runtime.so to be in **/data/data/{app}/lib** while `System.load("/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so");` requires the full path.

So none of your calls is correct. The answer is `System.load("/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so");`